# Making PNG image emit light

Tags: rendering, node-editor, image

[image: Node Setup]

The goal is to make the photo emit light so that it doesn't need any external light sources for it to show up in render, kind of like how this tutorial does it..
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Thmh7e_UP94

However the transparency is the key issue for me, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Clarification: when i mean show up in render, i mean have the image brighter

Comment: drive the color of the emission from the image as well.  You may not need the diffuse, depending on exactly what effect you want.  If you do, you need to change the fac on the last mix shader.  right now it's ignoring the emission